# android java A* Pathfinding help needed

Tags: java, android, path-finding

I have come across the following link:
http://code.google.com/p/a-star/source/browse/trunk/java/PathFinder.java?r=8
I have got the code working ok as a test but I am 
unsure how you change the destination node -- the default is bottom
right but I am unsure how you would change it to a different row/column
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems that the goal is defined in the function

```
            protected boolean isGoal(Node node){
                            return (node.x == map[0].length - 1) && (node.y == map.length - 1);
            }
```

change it to your needs.

Comment: thanks for that -- one other problem is that the code does not find all paths, it only seems to be able to scan a path from left to right not say all over, do you or anyone else know how easy it would be to change -- the code is ideal for what I want apart from the fact it only scans left to right...thansk

Comment: do you mean the starting position of the algorithm? you can change that in the Node constructor.

Comment: no I mean the code only seems to find paths going from top left to bottom right, not for example left - right - left - left down - left  even if there is a valid path of 1's in the array. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is in this part of the code:

```
protected List<Node> generateSuccessors(Node node){
                List<Node> ret = new LinkedList<Node>();
                int x = node.x;
                int y = node.y;
                if(y < map.length - 1 && map[y+1][x] == 1)
                                ret.add(new Node(x, y+1));

                if(x < map[0].length - 1 && map[y][x+1] == 1)
                                ret.add(new Node(x+1, y));

                return ret;
}
```

This code is returning a list of neighbours for the current node, however it only tries down and right directions. Try adding corresponding code for any other directions you wish to follow, e.g.

```
if(y > 0 && map[y-1][x] == 1)
                ret.add(new Node(x, y-1));
if(x > 0 && map[y][x-1] == 1)
                ret.add(new Node(x-1, y));
```

from

[A* Pathfinding java not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25804431/a-pathfinding-java-not-working-properly)

It works but execution is very slow , any suggestion to reduce execution time ???