# A* Pathfinding java not working properly

Tags: java, android, algorithm, graph-algorithm, path-finding

I am creating a Maze game in java and wants to add a smarty ghost (like Pacman) that move towards user location to catch him. For smarty ghost I chose A* PathFinding Algorithm and found below links for implementing this algorithm :

https://code.google.com/p/a-star/source/browse/trunk/java/PathFinder.java?r=8

https://code.google.com/p/a-star/source/browse/trunk/java/AStar.java?r=8

But the code is not completely working properly , I mean the code only seems to find paths going from top left to bottom right, not for example left - right - left - left down .

for e.g :

if

```
 source = (0,0)
 Destination = (8,8)     // works perfectly..
```

if

```
  source = (8,8)
  Destination = (0,0)     // doesn't  work :(
```

Please help me to correct this code or give useful link for implementing this.

Comment: Correct what code? You haven't shown any. To be honest you will need to narrow it down yourself first anyway. To be useful your question needs to be a lot more specific than "make this work".

Comment: @TimB I have given links that I followed and want to correct it OR share anything else related A* algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is in this part of the code:

```
protected List<Node> generateSuccessors(Node node){
                List<Node> ret = new LinkedList<Node>();
                int x = node.x;
                int y = node.y;
                if(y < map.length - 1 && map[y+1][x] == 1)
                                ret.add(new Node(x, y+1));

                if(x < map[0].length - 1 && map[y][x+1] == 1)
                                ret.add(new Node(x+1, y));

                return ret;
}
```

This code is returning a list of neighbours for the current node, however it only tries down and right directions.  Try adding corresponding code for any other directions you wish to follow, e.g.

```
if(y > 0 && map[y-1][x] == 1)
                ret.add(new Node(x, y-1));
if(x > 0 && map[y][x-1] == 1)
                ret.add(new Node(x-1, y));
```

Comment: After implementing your solution it works in all points , but execution become very slow, in some cases it take 2 or more mints . Any suggestion for increasing its execution ???

Comment: That is strange - I wonder how large is your grid?  I would have expected A* to be near instantaneous for this problem, perhaps you could try profiling the code to see what is taking the time?  Also check to see which nodes are being explored in case the heuristic is inaccurate.

Comment: I have just used [11][9] 2-D Matrix as in example, when I used  source = (8,8) and dest = (8,0) it took result in 2+ mints. I am finding the part of code that make it slow .

Comment: Execution time is too much, any suggestion ?

Comment: I tried a lot to reduce its execution time , but unfortunately didn't get any success. @PeterdeRivaz can u or someone plz help in this problem.

Comment: Try changing your functions to print out every time they are being called and check which nodes are being explored.  There should only be at most 11*9 nodes explored, which should take no time at all.